# Interactive flowchart in javascript

Tags: javascript, diagram, flowchart

Is there any free library for building interactive flowcharts? (i.e. drag and drop items)
I found http://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html which is awesome but it is not free.

Answer (score 0):

[jsplumb](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/) sounds like what you're looking for. They have a community edition that can be downloaded for free :)